# RxAndroid c Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit

Есть интерфейс

```
 @GET("/data, 2.5/forecast/daily")
Observable<MultilingualWeather> getWeatherByIdWithMultilingual(
        @Query("id") String id,
        @Query("lang") String lang,
        @Query("appid") String appid
);
```

который вызывается в MainActivity со следующей конфирурацией

```
Retrofit retrofit_weather = new Retrofit.Builder().
            baseUrl(BASE_URL).
            addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).
            addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()).
            build();

    GetWeatherForLocation getWeather = retrofit_weather.create(GetWeatherForLocation.class);

 Observable<MultilingualWeather> call_observable = getWeather.
            getWeatherByIdWithMultilingual(
            CITY_ID,
            LANG,
            KEY
    ).cache();

    subscription = call_observable.subscribe(subscriber);
```

В файле зависимостей следующее

```
 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.16'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta1'
```

}

и после всего этого вылетает исключение

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.alex.weatherclient, PID: 16658 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "retrofit.CallAdapter retrofit.CallAdapter$Factory.get(java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.annotation.Annotation[], retrofit.Retrofit)"
```

Comment: Попробуйте так:   Retrofit retrofit_weather = new Retrofit.Builder().
                addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()).
                addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).
                baseUrl(BASE_URL).
                build();

Comment: к сожалению не работает, но появилась другая ошибка FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.alex.weatherclient, PID: 2379
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented at retrofit.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.get(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java)

Comment: Попробуйте обновить зависимости в gradle и не применяйте изменения в комментарие выше: compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить  `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta1'` на `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'`

Comment: собственно столкнулся с такой же проблемой, это мне помогло